# avoid fancybox ajax- loader animation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fancybox, fancybox-2

I using fancybox all is done all I want is to "avoid" the ajax-loader of fancybox

the reason is I have already set a loading for all ajax request now everytime is make request using fancybox I see two loader appearing which kind of look ugly

Is there a way to do It

I went through the api and found a method called

`$.fancybox.hideLoading();`

but this doesnot seem to work as I see the loading still getting displayed

any idea

Regards

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found a Solution to it using CSS

```
<style>
 #fancybox-loading {
  display:none !important;
}
</style>
```

Can anyone suggest better than this

awaiting for correct answer

Comment: better than this is Janis' answer

Comment: @JFK got it man but by the time the `Janis` answer popped in I had already implemented my approach

Comment: @JKF yaa but `awaiting for the better` for the reader who come looking for answer for something like it but since I already mention my implementation too was working and it worked for me and mind you it far better to me since found it at time when I really need nothing against `Janis` though and I bet on one thing for sure that my approach is not that bad too so go ahead and `downvote` my answer does bother me even a bit.

Comment: Your solution hides loading icon completely. And if you decide to use fancyBox, for example, to display images, then the loading icon would not appear. So, it would be better 1) to override `$.fancybox.showLoading` method 2) or even better would be to check `$.fancybox.isActive` before displaying your custom loading icon. Well, it depends on your needs and we can not tell what suits better for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can override any fancyBox method, for example -

```
$.fancybox.showLoading = function () {
    console.info('My loading');
}
```